# UIView not showing after being brought to the front

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

Currently I am trying to make a circle over a camera feed. To do so I have created another UIView, set the frame/color/cornerRadius, added it to the self.view's subviews, and then brought the circle UIView to the front. For some reason it is not showing up.

I have done this before and I have coded it exactly the same as I did before but it still isn't showing.

Here is where I make the view:

```
//----Circle View----------
    circleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 100, height:  100))
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = self.circleView.frame.width/2
    circleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    circleView.layer.zPosition = 1
    //self.circleView.isHidden = true
    self.view.addSubview(circleView)
```

Here is where I bring it to the front:

```
 if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(dataOutput))!
    {

        captureSession?.addOutput(dataOutput)
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: circleView)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: captureButton)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: stopButton)

        previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds

    }
```

Is there a way I can get the circleView to show?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `Debug View Hierarchy` ... Does it actually exist in the hierarchy? If so, is the z-order somehow wrong, so it's hidden behind something? Or, are the  frames wrong, so it's being placed outside the view bounds?

Comment: You might need to add constraints to your `circleView`

Comment: Also you can try to put this line `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: circleView)` at the end(after `previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds`

Comment: give your previewLayer a zPosition of 1 and give the controls (or in this case, the circle view) a zPosition of 2

Comment: Thanks for the help. On the Debug view hierarchy, it says that the view is along the same level as the other Views that are showing up over the previewLayer. Could it be that existing constraints are interfering with the circleView being seen?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

To fix this I added a UIView to my storyboard and then created an IBOutlet to the view controller. After that, the view showed up. I'm thinking it was because I had existing constraints on the views in my storyboard that interupted the viewing of the circleView. That's my guess.